# The harsh password change

Tags: story, password, cipher

My roommate changed my password!  The jerk got onto my machine, while I was in the restroom, and changed it.

Sigh...

As he left the room, he gave me a single slip of paper, that he claimed had a password hint on it.

It simply states:

> 6-sided
> Very Harsh
> 28 characters

...Not that I have any idea what **that's** supposed to mean!
Well, anyhow.  The only things left on my desk, when he was gone were:

> A single `1 gram weight`
> and
> [image: Dollar Coin]

This is ridiculous... Would you guys mind helping me, please?

## UPDATE!

My roommate came back!  He was upset that I hadn't figured out the password, yet, though.  He grabbed a marker from his desk, drew on the coin, and walked back out the door, without saying another word.

## Hint

## 1

> The coin has absolutely nothing to do with the answer, but it's got the most important part.

## 2

> There are more 6-sided things than you've taken time to consider.

## 3

> The answer is 28 Nibbles long.

## 4

> One of the clues contained in the image has a particular feature which is extremely important towards deciphering the password.

## 5

> The gram is indicative of a specific type of arrangement....one that has to do...with grams.  ... Or a gram.

## Conclusion

With Bolo's help,  I was able to get into my computer finally!

When I finally made it in:

.... He had wiped my hard drive ...

Comment: To get started: The image shows the "Sacagawea Golden Dollar", but with "Liberty" mirrored. See: http://www.coinnews.net/2007/09/06/sacagawea-golden-dollar-scheduled-for-face-lift-3568/

Comment: And the note means.... Die Hard Alphabet?

Comment: @Duncan Amusing coincidences

Comment: Sorry for the delayed edit.   Dns server died at work.

Comment: does your roommate have any habits/features that might help us hone in on his thought process at all?

Comment: He's really messy.   I don't think I've ever seen anything of his in order.

Comment: very harsh = severe

Comment: Liberty might be a reference to "Live Free" as in "Live Free or Die Hard" not sure what to make of it being backward. Unless it means to flip it over. Take a look at the reverse on Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacagawea_dollar

Comment: @HughMeyers Code Talkers... Coincidence? except that's the 2003 version, not 2016...

Comment: A 1 gram weight and a coin that weighs 8.1 grams, could have something to do with money outweighing something or tipping the scales.

Comment: There's definitely something peculiar about this puzzle having the coin and a gram....

Comment: Forget your password, [coin errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mint-made_errors) are typically quite valuable, especially a never-before-seen one like this!

Comment: Ok. So 26 nibbles and 6 sided makes me think the password is in hex. And it's 26 hex chars meaning it either is 13 letters long or 26 hex chars that can be derived elsewhere from ascii values.

Comment: Are the word “6-sided” on the paper and the hexagon drawn on the brass buck supposed to convey separate pieces of information?  Seems like a redundant clue.

Comment: Because it was getting ignored. :-)

Comment: I'm starting the think that "change" in the title may refer to money change. Worth considering.

Comment: Hey @Khale_Kitha I think another hint is needed on this one. I get how the password is supposed to look and be made, but I don't think it's possible with available clues to figure out what it is.

Comment: It's more than possible to be solved with the current amount of information, but I'll consider adding something.

Comment: Possibly useful? http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/lzhang10/ngram.html

Comment: I don't think so - but I know nothing about N-Gram.

Comment: @all Please note that the slip of paper had an incorrect value and has been updated!

Comment: After all that? Haha. Gotta rethink the whole thing now... @Khale_Kitha

Comment: I know.   Sorry!   Blame it on my "roommate".  He wrote it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The password is: `5445525249424C59534556455245`, which is a hexadecimal representation of `TERRIBLYSEVERE`, which is an anagram of `REVERSE LIBERTY`.

Some of the hints:

- `6-sided` — hexadecimal
- `28 nibbles` — 14 letters coded as 28 hexadecimals
- `1 gram`, `I don't think I've ever seen anything of his in order.` — anagram
- `harsh` / `very harsh` — the 14-letter message is a harsh one
- `LIBERTY` reversed — could point to the other side of the coin, where `E PLURIBUS UNUM` is written (13 letters, too short), or to something else.

Comment: I approve this message!  LoL

Comment: I still don't get why 6-sided should point to hex, apart from hexadecimal beginning with the same letters as hexagon (but that's a stretch). Hexadecimal means 16, not 6.

Comment: @fffred I assume that's because in IT we sometimes say "hex" when referring to hexadecimal. You're right, that's not entirely accurate, but not a yuge (as politicians say these days) stretch.

Comment: Hex is the short form of hexadecimal. The number 6 is intended to lean you in the right direction, not give you the word. The clue was pointing to the word hex, not necessarily hexagon. It's further hinted with nibble to assist. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is the correct answer, good job. :)

Answer (score 6):

Is it:

> 65706c757269627573756e756d which is e pluribus unum in hex.

Because:

> The liberty reverse hints to the back side of the Sacajawea Dollar and on the 2003 "e pluribus unum" was on the back.
>
>  There have been plenty of hints toward hex and once e pluribus unum was mentioned in a hint, khale mentioned people were close.
>
>  Making a password hex is very harsh
>
>  It's 26 characters long.
>
>  Plenty of other hints were given in comments.
>
>  One as many is the translation which would account for the one gram weight.

Could also be:

> 31206772616d20776569676874

Comment: You're on the on the right track, but the gram holds more weight than you're giving it credit for.  (pun intended)

Comment: Hahahahaha. Nice one @Khale_Kitha

Comment: Is it something about a rot13(Xvyy-b-tenz)

Comment: Hah - nope.  "Ask again later"

Comment: @Khale_Kitha still thinking that was a hint on this. Is it or was it supposed to be a pun?

Comment: You're looking at it too close.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha unless it's my appended answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Not an Answer

The comments were getting too crowded.

Regarding the coin, you can see what a real one looks like [here](http://www.usacoinbook.com/coins/3388/dollars/sacagawea/2003-P/). Because the "tails" side of a coin is technically known as the reverse, and the word "LIBERTY" is reversed in the puzzle, I thought it might be significant to see the reverse of the coin. The P in the lower right means that it was minted in Philadelphia.

Utah is six sided, as Gamow points out. So are cells in beehives and snowflakes.

Almost certainly unrelated but I thought [this](http://www.storymuseum.org.uk/stories/26-characters-exhibition/) was interesting.

A one gram weight is really small. An American cent weighs about 2.5 grams. A paperclip weighs about a gram. On the other hand, sometimes grams are written things (like a hexagram?)

Harsh can mean caustic, severe or cruel

Liberty backwards could mean slavery or confinement of some sort. According to OP, none of his roommate's things are "in order". Maybe liberty isn't the only thing that's backward.

The longest Die Hard movie title, "Die Hard With a Vengeance" is 25 characters, including spaces.

Comment: US stop signs, however, are eight-sided.

Comment: Perhaps it is related to the Navajo Code Talkers; from 6-sided Utah; commemorated on 2016 reverse of Sacagawea Dollar.

Comment: @Gamow Maybe. But the reverse of the 2003 coin is an eagle in flight and the motto "e pluribus unum".

Comment: *Hand over mouth* You guys are getting SO many of the clues!  They just aren't being connected together, correctly.  (And you're all really focused on death.)

Comment: Maybe changing the hexagon into a hexagram and looking at what would be on the edges of the coin at the points? The Sacajawea Dollar has writing on the outside edge.

Comment: @Z.Dailey I don't have access to American coins. The letters on the edge are a long shot. There were none until 2007, I think, when e pluribus unum was moved to the edge from the reverse.

Comment: Why is Liberty spelled backward...

Comment: ...It's not. :)

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> 53746172206F66204461766964

That is,

> the 26-character **hex**-encoded ASCII code for “Star of David”, which is a **hex**a**gram**?  The backwards word on the coin could be a reference to the Hebrew script being written right-to-left.

Comment: You're close but not quite there.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha: So, are you saying I have the right coding, but of the wrong phrase?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is one of the following codes

> 456121612, 216121654 or 432161216.
>  Using a hexagon (which is 6-sided), numbering the nodes clockwise, and ordering the alphabet (26 letters) around it clockwise, the first corner contains the 1, a, g, m (one-a-gram), perhaps also alluding to the word "anagram", a rehash of letters.
>  The code is simply the code for the letters of "Very Harsh" (9 digits); the first guess.
>  The reverted Liberty could point to either the reverse of the first guess, which is my second guess. Or, if the hexagon is numbered reverse, then the code is the third guess, changing each digit n in 8-n, unless it's 1.

Comment: I don't think "very harsh" is a code as it used to be "harsh" and was edited afterwards

Comment: This is not it.  See the other answers for clues.

Answer (score 1):

It's time to start guessing. Therefore, my guess is:

> 562756675637E6F67616875686 This is the hex for "hexagonsevere" all backwards
>  6572657665736E6F6761786568 This is the hex for "erevesnogaxeh"

My reasoning:

> We have the clue that it is 26 nibbles, or half-bytes long. This solution has 26 hex characters which could be considered 26 nibbles corresponding to the 13 characters in "hexagonsevere". "hexagonsevere" of course comes from a hexagon being six-sided and severe meaning very harsh. I assume it has to be reversed in some way because the word "Liberty" is reversed and the picture of Sacagawea looking *back* over her shoulder is outlined with a hexagon. I am taking "gram" in the sense of something written as in "telegram" or "electroencephalogram" and "one gram" to mean the two clues are written all as one word.

If I'm not right, I hope this will at least provoke another clue.

Comment: You're using the right thought process here, but you've got a few details wrong, causing you to not reach the correct final solution.  Just remember that the puzzle involves a coin (which is not important, as such) ...and a gram.